# a variable/function can be declared any number of times but it can be defined only once

Tags: c, variables, declaration, definition

a variable/function can be declared any number of times but it can be defined only once.
What does that actually mean??

I tried to understand that statement on online compilers and I was expecting to show error but it didnt.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int x=10;

int main() {
    x=20;
    x=30;

    printf("%d",x);
}
```

expected output: i expected to show error because i have defined variable x and assigned three different values 10,20,30. the concept says you can declare variable any number of times but can define only once since two different locations cant be given to the same variable
actual output: 30

Comment: Variables would be mostly useless if you could only assign a value to them once

Comment: @ChrisTurner There are many programming languages that operate exactly like that, and which are very useful.

Comment: They are called variables for a reason too...

Comment: @RATAN the variable is declared only once, when you do `int x ...`. What you did several time was assigning a value to the variable.

Answer (score 10):

`x = 10;` isn’t a *definition*. It’s an *assignment*. You can assign as many times as you like.

`int x;` is a *definition* (and, at the same time, also a declaration). Likewise, `extern int x;` is a *declaration* (without a definition). To illustrate the concept you were asking about, the following is valid C:

```c
// Duplicate declaration: OK
extern int x;
extern int x;

// Definition: OK
int x;
// int x; // Duplicate definition: ERROR

// Definition with initialisation: OK
int y = 42;

// (Re)assignment: OK inside function.
x = 1;
y = 2;
```

For functions, the syntax is different. To declare a function, write its prototype. To define it, add a function body:

```c
// Declaration:
int f(void);
// Also possible, but unnecessary:
extern int f(void);

// Definition:
int f(void) { return 42; }
```

Comment: Nice answer. I got a few things wrong, and when I saw your answer I did not see the point in correcting my answer. Upvoted.

Comment: @Broman: That's a shame: Stack Overflow works best when there are multiple answers.

Comment: @Bathsheba This answer covered everything I wanted to say. There's no point in adding an answer if your answer does not provide anything new.

Comment: *x = 10; isn’t a definition. It’s an assignment.*  The `x = 10` portion is an *initialization*, and that's different from an assignment.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I was talking about the standalone statement, not the fragment `x = 10` as part of the statement `int x = 10;`.

Answer (score -1):

I just wanted to add that you *would* get an error if you had defined the variable as a constant, i.e.

```c
const int x = 10;

x = 15; // This will throw a compile-time error
```

As constants may only be assigned once during definition, hence the name constant.

https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-variables-constants